# Is it possible to be matched up with a member of your ignore list?

Tags: league-of-legends

If you ignore somebody, are they still viable possibilities to be a future teammate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, yes.

Ignore only prevents them from showing up in chat, you can't "Ignore" them from the matchmaking pool.

Comment: What a shame...

Comment: @Fabián not really, it would be extremely abusable

Comment: Yeah, let's just ignore anybody who beats me so I will never lose :D

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can . It is a problem though because if you are on draft mode selection  , you will not be able to see what they write on chat ( very important for ranked games).

It is said to be less possible to match with ignored users, but I am not sure if this is true .